# How to checkout a tagged version rather than the HEAD from CVS using IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

I need to checkout a tagged version (not the head) from CVS using IntelliJ. I am not going to change the tagged version but only to test on it.

It is very easy to be done in Eclipse. But in IntelliJ IDEA, I do not have any idea. (I am beginning to doubt that it is an easy-to-use IDE ...)

Please help.

Comment: I'm not expert in CVS but with SVN you should checkout folder like <repository>/<project>/tags/<version>. I hope adopted this from CVS and you can use this

Comment: please check http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/specifying-a-version-to-work-with.html

Comment: @lena My CVS repository contains hundreds modules, while each has dozens tags. If I do it according to that article, IntelliJ will take very long to load all tags from the repository, and then I have to choose the right tag from a long list with at least thousands tags, without knowing which module they belong to. So I do not think it is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in "Check out from CVS Repository" on pulling a new project.
Click configure on the right,
This will open up your CVS connections. hit the copy button in the middle and make a new one and then pick your tag "BY Tag"  then you don't have to worry about syncing that project cause it will be tied to the branch